# Subtotals, not groups, using LINQ?

Tags: .net, vb.net, linq

My goal: I have a 1 GB csv file I'm trying to summarize.  Let's say the file has "fields" / columns A-M.  I'd like certain fields subtotaled over another field, say A.  The results I'd like are each value in field A with subtotals of three other fields - say B, G, and L.

The problem: I'm trying to process this with a LINQ query, but Out of Memory exceptions are thrown.

Here's my query:

```
Dim summarizedRecs = From line In System.IO.File.ReadLines(filepath)
       Skip 1
       Let e = New aRecord(line)
       Group e
       By e.A
       Into g = Group
       Select summarizedR = New With {
           A,
           .TotalB = g.Sum(Function(x) x.B),
           .TotalG = g.Sum(Function(x) x.G),
           .TotalL = g.Sum(Function(x) x.L)}
       Order By summarizedR.A
```

`aRecord` is a simple class who's constructor takes a line of text and parses that line into appropriate fields.  That works fine.

This approach works fine for smaller files ~ 100 MB.  Memory used by the application increases over the runtime for the 100 MB file and the 1 GB file.

I suspect LINQ groups are not what I want here, but I'm not sure of another LINQ approach.  Is there one?

I think LINQ is keeping all my instances of e in the groups.  In the end, I don't need groups of e's.  After each e's fields are added to the appropriate group, that e can be disposed of.  I just want the resulting subtotals that come from the groups of e's.

I've also skipped LINQ all together and successfully implemented this using a Dictionary(Of T1, T2).  Doing that, I read each line of text, create an instance of aRecord and apply it's totals to the appropriate key-value pair in the the Dictionary.  In this approach there is only ever one instance of aRecord. This is efficient memory-wise -- the memory consumed levels off and stays relatively low.

So the Dictionary approach works on the 1 GB file.  Is there a LINQ alternative though?

Comment: You know the term _database_? ;-) Apart from that, if the `Dictionary` approach works, use it.

Comment: Yes, yes, yes... no write/import access to one currently.  A SQL GROUP BY would be what I'd be going for here in terms of results.

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing wrong with sticking with your `Dictionary` solution, but if you want to use a LINQ, you could use `Aggregate`:

```
Dim summarizedRecs = File.ReadLines(filepath) _
                         .Skip(1) _
                         .Select(Function(line) New aRecord(line))
                         .Aggregate(New Hashtable(), Function(acc, cur) 
                                                        acc(cur.A) += cur : Return acc
                                                     End Function)
```

and an `aRecord` class that implements an `+`-operator for convenience:

```
Private Class aRecord
    Public Property A As String
    Public Property B As Integer
    Public Property G As Integer
    Public Property L As Integer
    Public Shared Operator +(a As aRecord, b As aRecord) As aRecord
        If a is Nothing Then Return b

        Return New aRecord() With { _
            .A = a.A, _
            .B = a.B + b.B, _
            .G = a.G + b.G, _
            .L = a.L + b.L _
        }
    End Operator
End Class
```

I use a `Hashtable` here instead of `Dictionary` because a `Hashtable` returns `Nothing` if a specific key was not found, and abuse this fact in the `+`-operator (just to save some lines of code).

I also don't know what your `aRecord` class does otherwise, but in this example I abuse it to store the accumulated fields `B`, `G`, and `L` (again, to save some lines of code).

But, in a real-world application, I would probably use a simple `For Each` loop instead of trying to be clever.

Comment: I definitely didn't know how to use Aggregate.  That's helpful.

I was kind of hoping for a solution using anonymous types.  I thought they would make it easier to switch the grouping field or use multiple fields.

Comment: Thanks, Dominic, for the fast response and very clear, clean write up.